# how to copy files from sftp to amazon s3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

How to copy files from SFTP server to amazon-S3 using java? I don't want to download the data to local ,all data should be full copied to S3 bucket to destined path

Comment: If you have to use Java and don't want to copy to your local machine, then that leaves running your Java program on the SFTP host...

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to run programs on the SFTP server, (via SSH or a web page), then you can perform the upload on the same host that the file is stored.

If that's not possible, then you'll need to retrieve the file from SFTP and upload it to S3. You'll get the best performance by doing that from an EC2 instance, but you can do it from any host.

There are some services like [FTP2Cloud](https://www.ftp2cloud.com/) that do this as well.

Comment: I think this the best solution. One thing you could do is create VPC endpoint to S3 and transfer files from EC2 to S3 over private ips. This is more cost effective and secure.